# Upload local image in Angular5 / Ionic3 to Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic3, firebase-storage

I can easily upload images this way (select input file) :

```
import { AngularFireStorage } from 'angularfire2/storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<div>'
      + '<input class="file-input" type="file" (change)="selFile($event.target.files)">'
      + '<button (click)="startUpload()">Upload</button>'
      + '</div>',
})

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private storage: AngularFireStorage
  ) {}
  selectedFile: any;
  selFile(event: FileList) {
    this.selectedFile = event.item(0);
  }
  startUpload() {
    const file = this.selectedFile;
    const path = `test/${new Date().getTime()}_${file.name}`;
    this.task = this.storage.upload(path, file)
  }
}
```

This way, all works fine.

But I want to upload an image taken with @ionic-native/camera, something like this :

```
import { AngularFireStorage } from 'angularfire2/storage';
import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera';

@Component({
  template: '<div>'
    + '<img src={{pathForImage(lastImage)}} style="width: 100%">'
    + '<button (click)="takePic()">Take Picture</button>'
    + '<button (click)="startUpload()">Upload</button>'
    + '</div>',
  })

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private storage: AngularFireStorage,
    private camera: Camera,
  ) {}
  selectedFile: any;
  selFile(event: FileList) {
    this.selectedFile = event.item(0);
  }
  startUpload() {
    const file = this.selectedFile;
    const path = `test/${new Date().getTime()}_${file.name}`;
    this.task = this.storage.upload(path, file)
  }
  public takePic() {
    var options = {
      quality: 100,
      sourceType: sourceType,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
      correctOrientation: true
    };
    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imagePath) => {
      var currentName = imagePath.substr(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      var correctPath = imagePath.substr(0, imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      this.copyFileToLocalDir(correctPath, currentName, this.createFileName());
    }
  }
  private copyFileToLocalDir(namePath, currentName, newFileName) {
    this.file.copyFile(namePath, currentName, cordova.file.dataDirectory, newFileName).then(success => {
      this.lastImage = newFileName;
    });
  }
  public pathForImage(img) {
    if (img === null) {
      return '';
    } else {
      return cordova.file.dataDirectory + img;
    }
  }
}
```

So, I can upload an image to Firebase Storage. And I can take a picture with @ionic-native/camera.

But I don't know how to upload the image taken with the camera to Firebase Storage.

How can I upload the image in {{pathForImage(lastImage)}} the same way as in the first example ???

Comment: You want to select an image from input. Next, show it in img tag et click the button to upload?

Comment: I have the code to select a file or take a picture. This works fine. And the result is stored in myImageToUpload. But I don't know how to upload myImageToUpload.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you try to use this to select file in the phone memory:

```
<input type="file" (change)="selFile($event.target.files)">
```

or this to capture file

```
<input class="file-input" type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*"(change)="selFile($event.target.files)">
```

So, 2 inputs have `change` event for you to get the file to upload.

As you use `Ionic`, you must include this [plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer/) `file-transfer` and upload your image like this :

```
public uploadImage() {
  // Destination URL
  var url = "http://yoururl/upload.php";

  // File for Upload
  var targetPath = this.pathForImage(this.lastImage);

  // File name only
  var filename = this.lastImage;

  var options = {
    fileKey: "file",
    fileName: filename,
    chunkedMode: false,
    mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
    params : {'fileName': filename}
  };

  const fileTransfer: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();

  this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    content: 'Uploading...',
  });
  this.loading.present();

  // Use the FileTransfer to upload the image
  fileTransfer.upload(targetPath, url, options).then(data => {
    this.loading.dismissAll()
    this.presentToast('Image succesful uploaded.');
  }, err => {
    this.loading.dismissAll()
    this.presentToast('Error while uploading file.');
  });
}
```

Comment: Thierry, thanks for your help. But my problem is more related with Ionic3 and his native camera. So, I added more code to give more explanations.